# Split R data frame into smaller data frames based on string

Tags: r

I want to split this data frame: https://ibb.co/gJ2Xdfd into smaller data frames based on their rows. The top table is an aggregation of the totals of the subsequent tables so I don't need to read this data (as it's already contained in the other tables).

I've searched the df for occurrences of `Height (m)` that give me the rows to use as start and end points for splitting but I can't figure out how to use this vector iteratively

`occur <- which(df['1'] == "Height (m)")` gives me `[1]   2  17  33  49` but how do I use the different elements as start and end points iteratively in code like `df <- df[(occur[1]+1):(occur[2]-1), ]`

Comment: Try with `cumsum` i..e `i1 <- df['1'] == "Height (m)"; split(df, cumsum(i1))`  Please note that the code is not tested as you showed only an image.

Comment: If you have occur, then `start <- occur[-length(occur)] + 1; end <- occur[-1] - 1; Map(function(i, j) df[i:j,], start, end)`

Comment: Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3358272 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please just include the code or data (e.g., `dput(head(x))` or `data.frame(...)`) directly.

Comment: @akrun Thanks for that, it worked but - how do I read the last table considering it's not between the headers `Height (m)`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want all the rows where there is a number in the first column, apart from the first five rows that contain a number in the first column. Here's how you say that in R:

```r
df[grep("[[:digit:]]", df['1'])[-(1:5)],]
```